# UltraVNC 1.4.3.6 - Can't find argument when launching from a script that will span over multiple monitors

Tags: powershell, multiple-monitors, ultravnc

When running UltraVNC 1.4.3.6, I can span display over multiple monitors when launching the vncviewer.exe and selecting span over multiple monitors checkbox.  However, when launching this from a powershell script I can't seem to find an argument for this.  There is -fullscreen, this just puts it full screen without scrollbars on one monitor and doesn't span across 2.  Does anyone know if an argument exists for this?  It's not in any documentation that I can find.  Thanks!

Comment: Not UltraVNC specific, but have you seen this other question: https://superuser.com/q/1086133/141595 ? Also, have you tried playing with the `position`  and `scale` arguments of UltraVNC?

Comment: I messed around with -scale and that adjusted the size on my one monitor but did not span to the other monitor.  I will try position.  Not familiar with that one.  Thanks!

Comment: Launching vncviewer shouldn't depend on the environment. What's your vncviewer command and which parameter are you looking for?

Comment: I figured it out.  if you save your options you set in the gui it creates a file with all of the options, which you can edit, then you can just -config filename and it will use the settings in that file.

Comment: @Ron Glad to see you found a solution! Can you please write an answer (maybe with helpful screenshots) such that others that have a similar issue know how to resolve it in the future? It's fine to answer your own questions and better than leaving it in the comments as comments might be removed after a while.